# Post Method with React and redux

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, post, react-redux

I have a simple app for CRUD operations, now I can delete, edit, and display data, but I want to add new items to a list of users fetched from API(JSON server fake API) using react and redux.

**Now when I click add user and save the data only id is sent but other data are not sent.**

[image]

here is a live demo: [Redux live demo with source code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/throne1986/reduxa?file=/src/components/Users.js:453-667) .

Here is my form, AddUserForm.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import { addNewUser  } from '../redux/acitons/users/Users';

function AddUserForm({users}) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [newUserName, setNewUserName] = useState('');

   const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();

    const usersList = users;
    const newUserId = usersList[usersList.length - 1].id + 1;

    console.log("your name", newUserName);
    console.log("your id", newUserId)

    dispatch(addNewUser({
      ...users,
      id: newUserId,
      name: newUserName,
    }));

   }

  const handleCancel = () => {};
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{newUserName.id}</td>
      <td>
        <input
          value={newUserName}
          name="name"
          onChange={e => setNewUserName(e.target.value)}
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" className="btn outline" onClick={handleCancel}>
          <i className="material-icons">Cancel</i>
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-success btn-link"
          onClick={handleSubmit}
        >
          <i className="material-icons">save</i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
}

export default AddUserForm
```

and I call like this in parent components with the on click button.

```
{adding && <>
            <AddUserForm addNewUser={addNewUser} users={userData.users} />
   </>}
```

Here is a button in the parent components.

```
<button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-success btn-link btn-add"
          onClick={() => setAdding(true)}
        >
    <i className="material-icons">Add user</i>
</button>
```

What is wrong with my code? any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: have you checked this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806870/saving-canvas-to-json-and-loading-json-to-canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the debugging tools screenshot you are showing us the response body, not the request body.

`users` is an array, why this

```
dispatch(addNewUser({
  ...users,
  id: newUserId,
  name: newUserName,
}));
```

intead of this?

```
dispatch(addNewUser({
  id: newUserId,
  name: newUserName,
}));
```

The root cause of the problem **is** in `src/redux/acitons/users/Users`

```
export const addNewUser = data => {

  console.log("adding mother a new user", data);

  return dispatch => {
    axios.post("http://localhost:3000/users")
```

Just change last line in

```
    axios.post("http://localhost:3000/users", data)
```

I can see `data` in the `console.log` not in the POST.

This gives error with empty `usersList`.

```
const newUserId = usersList[usersList.length - 1].id + 1;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I changed that but still the same, u can clone the repo and test it on your side

Comment: The app opens with "Request failed with status code 404" maybe a back-end is missing?

Comment: @TheDeadMan anyway in the repos I cloned `data` is still missing in the POST request

Comment: Daniel sorry i didnt tell you , you need  first to run `json-server --watch users.json` and then on another terminal run  `yarn start` and u should see the data, am using json server fake api

Comment: @TheDeadMan I simply added `data` to the POST request and it worked... please check my edited answer

Comment: can you push ur repo to github? I changed mine but stil the same :(

Comment: can you prove if its working? I tried but still the same

Comment: @TheDeadMan my pull request is still open

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216098/discussion-between-the-dead-man-and-daniele-ricci).

Comment: Please run this command first. ```json-server --watch users.json```